# Изменение консольного вывода print() без использования cls

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Такая проблема, в программе есть цикл ожидания определенных действий от пользователя. Пока программа ожидает выполнение этих действий, на экран выводится "Ожидание..." `print("Ожидание...")`
чтобы пользователь не подумал, что программа зависла, надпись должна циклично изменяться, от `Ожидание...` до `Ожидание..` и так по кругу. Понятное дело, что это можно реализовать через `os.system("cls")`, но в таком случая **вся надпись** неприятно "мигает". Как сделать, чтобы перезаписывался не весь текст, а только точка в конце?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать для этого символ `\r` "возврат каретки". Вот в таком варианте, когда он в начале строки, это работает и в Google Colab. А так то если просто в терминале, то можно использовать и вариант с `end='\r'`:

```
import time

text = "Ожидание.."
flag = False

while True:
    print('\r' + text + ('.' if flag else ' '), end='')
    flag = not flag
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: А есть же ещё `\b`.

Comment: @206435 Ну, как вариант, да. Но `\r` вроде универсальнее как-то